# Image upload and display not work- Cakephp

Tags: image, cakephp

I'm trying to add upload image for every connected user

But I can't upload to databse

Error message :

Cannot convert value of type array to string

Edit : When I try update The User profile from (profile function) I get message : 
Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 0 [CORE\src\View\Helper\UrlHelper.php, line 174]

But when I update the profile From the Users (edit function) works fine

UsersController.php

```
public function edit($id = null)
{   
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('user');
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        if ($this->request->data['password'] == '') {
           unset($this->request->data['password']);
        }
          $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    unset($user->password); // Unset the password so nothing is loaded or displayed in the form
    $roles = $this->roles;
    $this->set(compact('user', 'roles'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    $this->set('user_session', $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User'));
}


public function profile()
{
    //Set Title
    $this->set('title', 'Profile');
    // Set the layout.
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('user');
    $this->set('user_session', $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User'));

      $Users = TableRegistry::get('Users');

    $user_data = $Users->get($this->request->session()- 
>read('Auth.User.id'));
    if($this->request->is('put') AND !empty($this->request->getData()) )
    {


        $userdata = $Users->patchEntity($user_data, $this->request->getData(), [
            'validate' => 'update_profile'
        ]);

        if($userdata->errors())
        {
            // Form Validation TRUE
            $this->Flash->error('Please Fill required fields');
        }else
        {
            $user_data->name    = $this->request->getData('full_name');
            $user_data->username   = $this->request->getData('username');
            $user_data->email   = $this->request->getData('email');
            $user_data->image = $this->request->data['image']['names'];

            //upload image
            if(!empty($this->request->data['file']['names'])){
            $filename = $this->request->data['file']['names'];
            $url = Router::url('/', true) . 'img/' . $filenames;
            print_r($url);
            exit();
            $uploadpath = 'img/';
            $uploadfile = $uploadpath . $filenames;
            if (move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
                $user_data->names = $filenames;
                $user_data->image = $url;
                }
                        }
            // Form Validation FALSE
            if($Users->save($user_data))
            {
                // User Session Update
                $this->request->session()->write('Auth.User.name', $user_data['full_name']);
                $this->request->session()->write('Auth.User.username', $user_data['username']);
                $this->request->session()->write('Auth.User.email', $user_data['email']);
                $this->request->session()->write('Auth.User.image', $user_data['image']);
                $this->redirect('/Users/Profile');
                $this->Flash->success('User has been Updated.');

            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update user!'));
            }

        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('user_data'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user_data']);
}
```

UsersTable.php

```
public function validationUpdate_profile(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
         // User Funll Name Validation
        ->notEmpty('full_name')
        // User Phone Validation
        ->notEmpty('email')
        ->allowEmpty('image')
        ->allowEmpty('image_dir');
    return $validator;
}
```

Profile.ctp
Im not sure about this either

Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 0 [CORE\src\View\Helper\UrlHelper.php, line 174]

```
<?= $this->Html->image($user_data->image, ['alt' => 'User image','style' => 'height: 250px; width: 100%; display: block;']); ?>

echo $this->Form->create($user_data, ['type'=>'file']);
echo $this->Form->input('image', ['value' => $user_session['image'], 'type'=>'file']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1) The way your code is written, the image upload block never gets called.

Lets assume you move the block to a place where it gets called. This worked on my setup. Note, I had to make a few changes to get it to work (like remove Route and change $this->request->getData to $this->request->data).

2) $this->request->data['image'] is an array. If you're trying to save the file name in $user_data->image you have to get $this->request->data['image']['name'].

Paste this in the proper area:

```
        }else
        {
            $user_data->name    = $this->request->data('full_name');
            $user_data->image   = $this->request->data['image']['name'];


            //upload image
            if(!empty($this->request->data['image']['name'])){
                $filename = $this->request->data['image']['name'];
                $url = WWW_ROOT . 'img/' . $filename;
                $uploadpath = 'img/';
                $uploadfile = $uploadpath . $filename;
                if (move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
                    $user_data->name = $filename;
                    $user_data->image = $url;
                }
            }

            // Form Validation FALSE
            if($Users->save($user_data))
```

I use this little block of code to help me figure out where the data for your image was being saved.

This is why I changed your ['file'] to ['image'].

I always use this to see if my data is coming through from my form or not.

```
    if($this->request->is('put') AND !empty($this->request->getData()) )
    {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->request->data);
            print_r($_FILES);
            echo '</pre>';
            die;
```

Comment: Update : after updating the profile for exemple when ever i change the name I get  
Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 0 [CORE\src\View\Helper\UrlHelper.php, line 174]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which line is line 174 in the controller code you have posted?